# Topology of sets defined by real-valued functions

Tags: general-topology, implicit-function

Suppose I have a topological space $S$ and a continuous real-valued function $f:S \to \mathbb R$. I can define sets like:
\begin{align}
A &= \{x \in S : f(x) = 0 \} \\
B &= \{x \in S : f(x) \le 0 \} \\
C &= \{x \in S : f(x) < 0 \} \\
\end{align}
What can we say about the topological relationships between $A, B, C$?

For example, is it true that $A$ is the boundary of $B$, or that $C$ is the interior of $B$. If those statements are not true, and we want them to be true, what extra conditions do we have to impose on $f$ or on the topology of $S$. I’d be happy to assume that $S$ is a metric space, or even a normed space, for example.

Context: these sorts of sets are used to model shapes in computer systems, so I’m interested in their topology.

Comment: For a counterexample, consider $f=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really say much without knowing the specifics of $f$. For example, even in a nice space like $S = \Bbb R$, consider the continuous function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases} -1 &x \leq -1 \\
x &-1 < x < 0 \\
0 &x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$ Then
\begin{align}
A &= \{x \in \Bbb R : f(x) = 0 \} = [0, +\infty) \\
B &= \{x \in \Bbb R : f(x) \le 0 \} = \Bbb R \\
C &= \{x \in \Bbb R : f(x) < 0 \} = (-\infty, 0) \\
\end{align}

So certainly $B$ is not the closure of $C$ and $A$ is not the boundary of $C$.

However, there is a condition that you can put of $f : S \to \Bbb R$ to ensure that $B = \overline{C}$ (for arbitrary topological space $S$). If $f$ is an **open map** in addition to being continuous, then
$$
\overline{f^{-1}(U)} = f^{-1}(\overline{U})
$$ is true. So
$$
\overline{C} = \overline{f^{-1}((-\infty, 0))} = f^{-1}(\overline{(-\infty, 0)}) = f^{-1}((-\infty, 0]) = B
$$

Comment: Thanks. And, according to the Wikipedia page on open mappings, their inverses preserve boundaries. So, I think this implies that A is the boundary of B.

Comment: @bubba Yes, another way to see that is: note that $C$ is open, being the continuous preimage of an open set. So since $\overline{C} = B$, $B^o = C$. And of course $A = B - C = \overline{B} - B^o = \partial B$.